# Laravel 5: return number of affected rows PGSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

I have such a query and I want to get how many records have been added or updated.

```
$insertData = Lpis::UpdateOrCreate(['objectid' => $insert[$i]['objectid']],['identyfikator' => $insert[$i]['identyfikator'],'powierzchnia' => $insert[$i]['powierzchnia'],'teryt' => $insert[$i]['teryt'],'numer' => $insert[$i]['numer'],'wojewodztwo' => $insert[$i]['wojewodztwo'],'powiat' => $insert[$i]['powiat'],'gmina' => $insert[$i]['gmina'],'data_od' => $insert[$i]['data_od'],'shape_leng' => $insert[$i]['shape_leng'],'shape_area' => $insert[$i]['shape_area']]);
```

Anyone help ?

Comment: `updateOrCreate()` will only update a single row.

Comment: Ok, but if will insert some data then can be many of them.

Comment: How do you mean? `updateOrCreate()` will only update or insert a single row.